# I created a stopwatch using JavaScript, and I'm trying to start/stop the timer by space key, but it doesn't stop but always became more faster

Tags: javascript

I created a stopwatch using JavaScript, and I'm trying to start/stop the timer by space key, but it doesn't stop but always became more faster.
'''

```
var timer_start = "S";

var time;
document.body.onkeyup = function (e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 32) {
    time = setInterval(timer, 10);
    if (timer_start == "S") {
      timer_start = "F";
    } else if (timer_start == "F") {
      clearInterval(time);
      timer_start = "S";
    }
  }
};
```

,,,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the spacebar is pressed, you are starting the timer again regardless of the current value of `timer_start`. You need to move this to be inside the `if` statement. I'd also recommend using a Boolean instead of the string `"S"` and `"F"`.

Here is my proposed rewrite of your code:

```
var timer_start = true;

var time;
document.body.onkeyup = function (e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 32) {
    if (timer_start) {
      time = setInterval(timer, 10);
      timer_start = false;
    } else {
      clearInterval(time);
      timer_start = true;
    }
  }
};
```

You could also shorten it a bit by doing this if you wanted

```
var timer_start = true;
var time;
document.body.onkeyup = function (e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 32) {
    if (timer_start) {
      time = setInterval(timer, 10);
    } else {
      clearInterval(time);
    }

    timer_start = !timer_start
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You set the interval regardless of the `timer_start` state, so you keep piling up new intervals and remove only half of them. You should set the interval only in the `timer_start == "S"` branch.